# telnet password is different than router password (zte router)?

Tags: router, telnet

i have that router ZXHN H108N V2.5 got it from my ISP ( Te-Data Egypt ) , the router are modified ..

when i try to login to my router using telnet that what i get :

```
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Password:
```

and the password is "admin" , but the router password is different on the webpage , how can i change that telnet password or close it ..

available commands on telnet :

```
ZTE>?
Exec commands:
  exit    Quit from telnet.
  ip      IP Ifconfig
  lan     About Lan Infomation
  rt      Wireless Parameter
  rtwlan  Wireless Parameter
  set     set
  show    show info
  sys     About System Infomation
  w       About DSL Line Information
  wan     About WAN Connection Information
```

Comment: I think there will be an option to change password for telnet or disable telnet in the web-based configuration. Isn't it? Otherwise you can check if there is a firewall inbuilt in modem which you can configure..

Comment: there is completely nothing ..

Comment: Is there atleast port forward feature in the router?

Comment: yeah there is port forward .

Comment: If your worry is someone accessing the Telnet via Internet then I think you can use port forward to prevent that. Simply port forward a 192.168.1.200:80 via 192.168.1.1:23. I think that should prevent Telnet accessible from internet. try it once.

Comment: This does not appear to be a security question. Your question seems to be "how do I change the telnet password on my router?" Try the router's manual? Ask your ISP's support?